# Bash: Add prefix before 'find' output

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm currently using:

```
find "$location" -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \;
```

This displays all directories in the current location. However, I would like to add "- " (a sort of bulletpoint) in front of every list item. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` has all of this built in.

```
find "$location" -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '- %f\n'
```

The sequence `%f` gets just the base name; `%h` is `dirname`, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `- %f\n`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' dir; do
   echo "- ${dir##*/}"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0)
```

Comment: If you're going to invoke bash, might as well reuse a single instance and iterate over multiple arguments to make it efficient.

Comment: Yes makes sense. Edited now.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Try this out:

```
#!/bin/bash
find "$location" -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \; | sed 's/^/- /'
```

This sends each line outputted from the find command into sed. sed then replaces the beginning of the line `^` with a `'- '`.

Answer (score 0):

This is more efficient than execing a program for each item:
(no newlines in filenames assumed)

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -type d |
sed 's:^.*/::; s:^:-:' #get basename and prepend -
```